# Teradata create date range window based on previous rows

Tags: sequence, teradatasql

Teradata DB

I am having a rough go at it.  I have a dataset and I want to create a customer journey.  The rules are that the first transaction is a journey.  The next transaction that is at least 30 days out is a journey.  The next transaction at least 30 days past that is also a journey.  I do not have access to programming, only regular queries.

There are a few scenarios.
Customer has just 1 transaction in the dataset.  Since it is the only one, it is flagged as a journey.

Customer has 2 transactions within 5 days.  The first one is a journey and the second one is not since it is within 30 days.

Customer has 2 transactions.  1/1 and 2/5.  They are > 30 days apart so each is flagged as a journey.

Customer has 3 transactions. 1/1, 1/8, 2/5.  The first and third are journeys and the second one is not (since it is within the 30 day window of a previously flagged journey).

I have tried everything, but there always seems to be some scenario that doesn't work.

I have the logic that I can write down, but I can't figure out how to do it in teradata.

1. If trans_idx=1 then journey flag = y
2. If date - previous trans_idx date > 30 then journey_flag = Y
3. This is what I can get right.  I can't get the sql right for the following logic.  If date - previous trans_idx date < 30 then I need to accumulate the difference and then sum the next row.  If it is still < 30 I need to accumulate and sum the next row.  Once it gets past 30, I need to set that rows' journey flag to Y.

This works but it only compares the previous row.  If I change it to unbounded, it will look at all the rows for the given sequence - i just need it to go back to previous 30 day end.

```
WHEN RUNNING_SUM_FLOAT=0 THEN 'Y'
 WHEN RUNNING_SUM_FLOAT - MIN(RUNNING_SUM_FLOAT)
          OVER (partition by sequence_id ORDER BY trans_idx
                ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING) >=30
   THEN 'Y'
   ELSE 'N'
END as journey_flag
```

Comment: You may be able to use the `sessionize` function for this.

Comment: Thanks, Fred. I checked that out and that is really interesting.  Sessionize would almost work for this.  However, it would not sessionize in the below scenario.  If I declare a 30 day session, the below 3 would all be in the same session.  I need 2/5 to be separated since it is outside the 30 day window from the first one.

Customer has 3 transactions. 1/1, 1/8, 2/5. The first and third are journeys and the second one is not (since it is within the 30 day window of a previously flagged journey).

Comment: Suppose if transactions happened on in the following way Case 1: 1st day,30th day and 31st day. Case 2: 1st day, 59th day and 60th day. Then how will you  classify them and into which journeys as per your requirement?